# Specify file pattern in pysftp get

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

We can write a simple `get` like this:

```
import pysftp

hostname = "somehost"
user = "bob"       
password = "123456"  
filename = 'somefile.txt'

with pysftp.Connection(hostname, username=user, private_key='/home/private_key_file') as sftp:
    sftp.get(filename)
```

However, I want to specify a pattern in the filename, something like: `'*.txt'`

Any idea on how to do this using `pysftp` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no function to download files matching a file mask in pysftp.

You have to:

- list the directory, using [`Connection.listdir`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir) or [`Connection.walktree`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.walktree) (if you need recursion)
- iterate the list of files, filtering the files you want
- call [`Connection.get`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) individually for each.

---

- For a trivial implementation, see:
  [List files on SFTP server matching wildcard in Python using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49381899/850848)

  It's about Paramiko, but the file matching part will be the same with pysftp:

  ```
  import fnmatch
  ```

  ```
  for filename in sftp.listdir('/remote/path'):
      if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, "*.txt"):
          sftp.get("/remote/path/" + filename, "/local/path/" + filename)
  ```

  Though your should really be using Paramiko anyway: [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)
- For a recursive example (you have to add the file matching), see:
  [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848#50130813).
- See also how [`Connection.get_d`](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-253) or [`Connection.get_r`](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-273) are implemented.

Answer (score 7):

Can confirm after going through the documentation that you can't list using a pattern. So i did something like this:

```
import pysftp
import re

server = pysftp.Connection(host=FTP_HOST,
                  username=FTP_USERNAME,
                  password=FTP_PASSWORD)
server.cwd(YOUR_FILES_PATH)
filelist = server.listdir()

for filename in filelist:
    filedate = re.search(".*\.txt$", filename)
    if filedate:
        print "FOUND FILE " + filename
```

Comment: got "IndentationError: unexpected indent" on this

Comment: @BobYoplait on which line u getting this exception? use pycharm it tells u about indentation exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pysftp
import sys

[...]

dn = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H");
with pysftp.Connection(myHost, myUsername, password=myPassword) as sftp:
    myFileList = sftp.listdir("files/")
    for filename in myFileList:
        if (filename.rfind("ArrivalList_" + dn) != -1):
            sftp.get("files/" + filename, "/tmp/" + filename)
```