# List files on SFTP server matching wildcard in Python using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, glob, paramiko

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='test1234', password='test')
path = ['/home/test/*.txt', '/home/test1/*.file', '/home/check/*.xml']
for i in path:

    for j in glob.glob(i):

        print j

client.close()
```

I am trying to list the wildcard files on remote server by using `glob.glob`. But `glob.glob()` is not working.

Using Python 2.6.

Remote server contains these files: `/home/test1/check.file`, `/home/test1/validate.file`, `/home/test1/vali.file`

Can anyone please help on this issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `glob` will not magically start working with a remote server, just because you have instantiated `SSHClient` before.

You have to use Paramiko API to list the files, like [`SFTPClient.listdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir):

```
import fnmatch
```

```
sftp = client.open_sftp()

for filename in sftp.listdir('/home/test'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, "*.txt"):
        print filename
```

You can also use a regular expression for the matching, if it suits your needs better. See [Using wildcard in remote path using Paramiko's SFTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51866185/850848).

---

*Side note: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy`. You
lose security by doing so. See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Answer (score 4):

Or use [pysftp](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/) which is *paramiko* wrapper and write something like this:

```
import pysftp


def store_files_name(fname):
    pass


def store_dir_name(dir_name):
    pass


def store_other_file_type(other_file):
    pass

with pysftp.Connection('server', username='user', password='pass') as sftp:
    sftp.walktree('.', store_files_name, store_dir_name, store_other_file_type)
```