# How to download folder by checking item inside it from remote server to local dir using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp, paramiko

In my root folder I have few folders.
For example:

```
root
  AAA
    a.txt
    a.xml
  BBB
   b.txt
   b.xml
  CCC
   c.xml
  DDD
   ......
```

I need to download all folder which contain .txt file inside it except DDD.
For example AAA, BBB has .txt file so I need to download it except CCC(as CCC didn't contain .txt)

I used the below code which download all file except DDD but am not able to check whether it contains .txt or not

Code I tried:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko
from stat import S_ISDIR

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('host', username='test', password='123')


remote_dir ='/root'
local_path = 'C:/download/'

def download_dir(remote_dir, local_dir):
    import os
    os.path.exists(local_dir) or os.makedirs(local_dir)
    dir_items = sftp.listdir_attr(remote_dir)
    for item in dir_items:
        # assuming the local system is Windows and the remote system is Linux
        # os.path.join won't help here, so construct remote_path manually
        if(item.filename != "DDD"):
            remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename      
            local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
            
                    
                    if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
                        download_dir(remote_path, local_path)
                
                    else:
                
                        sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
 

download_dir(remote_dir,local_path)
```

How can I check the files inside it and download the folder based on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob.glob(pathname, "*.txt") to get all txt files in a directory.

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: But I need to copy the folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import fnmatch
```

```
if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
    if any(fnmatch.fnmatch(f, "*.txt") for f in sftp.listdir(remote_path)):
        download_dir(remote_path, local_path)
else:
    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
```

It's bit inefficient, as you will list all subfolders twice. But you can optimize it easily, if needed.

Based on [List files on SFTP server matching wildcard in Python using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49381899/850848).