# How to run the command generated from awk with printf?

Tags: shell, awk

I want to create a shell script that will rename all `.txt` files from a specific directory in remote server by using SFTP (will download the files first then rename in remote server). Please check the attempt below:

```
sftp user@host <<EOF
cd $remoteDir
get *.txt
ls *.txt | awk '{printf "rename %s %s.done\n",$0,$0 ;}' 
exit
EOF
```

From the statement `ls *.txt | awk '{printf "rename %s %s.done\n",$0,$0 ;}'` it will generate and print out a list of `rename` command, my question is, how to run these command generated from `awk` `printf`?

Comment: Not clear, good that you have showed what you are trying but you missed the part telling us what is complete picture of your question, kindly do add more details and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have edited the post, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: do you want to rename the files on the server, or the copies that you downloaded?

Comment: @jhnc rename the files on server

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to rename files on the server but you only know what commands to run after you have downloaded the files.

The simple option would be to run two sftp sessions. The first downloads the files. Then you generate the rename commands. Then you run a second sftp session.

However it is possible to do both in one session:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
    # clean up from any previous run
    rmdir -f syncpoint

    # echo commands are fed into the sftp session
    # be careful with quoting to avoid local shell expansion
    echo 'cd remoteDir'
    echo 'get *.txt'
    echo '!mkdir syncpoint'

    # wait for sftp to create the syncpoint folder
    while [ ! -d syncpoint ]; do sleep 5; done

    # the files have been downloaded
    # now we can generate the rename commands
    for f in *.txt; do
        # @Q is a bash (v4.4+) way to quote special characters
        echo "rename ${f@Q} ${f@Q}.done"
        # if not available, single-quoting may be enough
        #echo "rename '$f' '$f'.done"
    done

    # clean up
    rmdir syncpoint

) | sftp user@host
```

Comment: +1 for cleverness but "it can be done" does not mean "it should be done". A tool which lets you run `sftp` in a subprocess would be much simpler and more robust. My choice would be Python but I'm sure it can be done with any modern scripting language.

Comment: @tripleee I can believe it's more robust if you're doing errorhandling. I don't know python but looking at paramiko docs, seems like one might end up with similar logic to this but just with more boilerplate. Probably worth it if problem is more complicated, not convinced simpler... :-)

Comment: There's a separate `pysftp` library which I believe should allow this to be done fairly succinctly.

Comment: yes, doesn't seem like a huge amount of boilerplate, although `get *.txt` doesn't seem completely trivial: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36329931/10971581

Comment: Maybe also mention that `${f@Q}` is a Bash v4.4+ feature.

Answer (score -3):

Hello Newbie please use this

```
sftp user@host <<EOF
cd $remoteDir
ls *.txt | awk '{printf "mv %s %s.done\n",$0,$0 ;}' | sh
exit
EOF
```

Comment: sorry I missed that with rename .. which should be `mv` try again

Comment: No, `mv` doesn't work in sftp, sftp need to use `rename`

Comment: which distro is the remote host??

Comment: I'm not sure sftp allows you to pipe `ls` into `awk` like this. Probably the `EOF` should be before the `ls` line (and the `get` line is missing).

Comment: Of course it does, I have tested but he did not said which distro is the remote host.